# c++ iostream, stringstream termination

Tags: c++, stream

I am programming simly TCP server, and I've got a problem with termination of stream.

I'm receiving some data,  defined that the end of data is combination `\r\n` ,but the stream is terminating on the first `\0` in this data.

```
bool read(char &chr_glob, stringstream &ss ){
    char chr;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    while (!ss.get(chr)){
        ss.clear();
        recv(c, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        ss<<buffer;
    }
    chr_glob = chr
    if ( chr == '\r' ){
        char tmp = ss.peek();
        if ( tmp == '\n'){
            ss.get(chr_glob);
            return false;
        }
    } 
    return true;
}
```

I was trying to use iostream , but I've get compilation problem, and don't know how to fix it.

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:40:0,
from robot.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:830:7: error: ‘std::basic_iostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_iostream() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is protected
basic_iostream()
^
robot.cpp:148:14: error: within this context
iostream ss;
^
```

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after `chr_glob = chr`.

Comment: Yeah, delete it while posting code,  it is not a problem. Thank you for notice.

Comment: The compiler error is in function `main`. Please post the `main` function code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the stream is terminating on the first \0 in this data.

```
ss<<buffer;
```

expects NULL-terminated C string (the NULL is used to determine data length). Use `write` for binary data:

```
size = recv(c, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
ss.write(buffer, size);
```

> I was trying to use iostream , but I've get compilation problem, and don't know how to fix it.

`iostream` is a base class. It cannot be instantiated directly. Use `stringstream` like you did.

Comment: @chrisaycock It is for the first half. I will add the second as well.